# Comando "switch" entre cai no "default"

Tags: javascript, switch

Para qualquer valor que digite, o resultado sempre é "Nenhuma das alternativas", onde está o erro?

Segue o código:

```
<body>
  <p>Clique para exibir...</p>
  <!-- <button onclick="myFunction()">Clique aqui</button> -->
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Clique aqui...</button>

  <script>
  function myFunction()  {
    var x=prompt("Digite o mes:");
    mes=x;
    switch (mes) {
      case 1:
        alert("janeiro");
        break;
      case 2:
        alert("Fevereiro");
        break;
      case 3:
        alert("março");
        break;
      case 4:
        alert("abril");
        break;
      case 5:
        alert("maio");
        break;
      default:
        alert("Nenhuma das alternativas")
    }
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

O principal problema é que não está convertendo a entrada de dados que sempre é uma `string` para um número que é o que está comparando.

Eventualmente poderia fazer isso com o *array* em vez de fazer um enorme `switch`.

```js
switch (parseInt(prompt("Digite o mes:"))) {
case 1:
    alert("janeiro");
    break;
case 2:
    alert("Fevereiro");
    break;
case 3:
    alert("março");
    break;
case 4:
    alert("abril");
    break;
case 5:
    alert("maio");
    break;
  default:
    alert("Nenhuma das alternativas")
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/Convert.js).

[Documentação do `parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).